# capturing internal audio java

Tags: java, audio, capture

i will record the sound from my programs. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and PulseAudio.
Now i try to record from pulseaudio but currently i'm only recording from my microphone.
How can i record the sound from pulseaudio instead of my microphone?

```
public static void captureAudio() {
    try {
        final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int bufferSize = (int)format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

            public void run() {
                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                running = true;
                try {
                    while (running) {
                        int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        if (count > 0) {
                            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread captureThread = new Thread(runnable);
        captureThread.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried some things to change this in my code:

```
Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
```

And then:

```
final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
```

Hope anyone have a solution.

Greetings
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This problem cannot be solved from within Java alone. Java sees only the devices which are already there, as the following Java program demonstrates:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class ListDevices {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
        for (final Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo())
            System.out.format("%s: %s %s %s %s%n", info, info.getName(), info.getVendor(), info.getVersion(), info.getDescription());
    }
}
```

What you need to do is create a loopback device for your audio system. The following post shows how to do that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype The purpose was different, but it should be adaptable for your situation, as your situation seems simpler to me than the situation described in that post.

It should be possible to run those `pactl` commands from Java using `Process`.

Comment: Thanks. Now i have one loop from my internal sound. But how can i access then from java? The Output from the list code is: http://pastebin.com/jXhkQ9n7

Comment: Give "PulseAudio Mixer" a try.

Comment: `public static AudioFormat getFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }`

Comment: And this: `Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()[0]);
            final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();`