# JAVA Sound API - Capturing audio from speaker

Tags: java, api, webrtc

I know how to capture audio from microphone and record audio from microphone and speaker using JAVA sound API. But I want to capture the audio that hears in speaker using JAVA...can anyone help me to find the solution? Or is there any way to automate voice path check in webRTC calls?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please provide those details, too.

Comment: There is no built-in, OS-independent way. For unix-likes, you may get some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473522/capturing-internal-audio-java, but that's unlikely applicable to Windows, where you would rather need a wrapper for WASAPI for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording